# How to convert complex conjugate impedance to a usual 50ohm impedance?

Tags: impedance-matching

Let's say I have a complex conjugate for a component (RD16HHF1 @ 30 MHz for example):
$$
Z = 2.93+j \cdot 3.51
$$
And I want to match that conjugate to a 50 Ohm.

If I had something like 10 Ohm to 50 Ohm I could use a 1:5 impedance transformer. But I don't understand how to use complex conjugate.
I do understand how I can get \$Z _C\$ or \$Z_L\$. That seems pretty clear to me.

I assume I couldn't just use only the real part of the conjugate. Or can I?

If I will take a only real part of the conjugate I am getting 2.93 Ohm.

I can use this formula to identify number of turns ratio for impedance matching:
$$
\frac{N_p}{N_s} = \sqrt{\frac{Z_p}{Z_s}}
$$

Which gives me the following
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2.93}{50}} \approx \frac{1}{4}  
$$

I saw a few practical applications and authors have been using 1:3 turns ratio in the transformer but didn't explain why. Still 1:4 is fairly close to 1:3.

I am puzzled.

Am I thinking the wrong way?
Are these authors wrong?
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> *If I had something like 10 Ohm to 50 Ohm I could use a 1:5
> transformer.*

Incorrect; if you had a transformer, it's the turns-ratio-squared that sets the impedance ratio of input and output hence, converting 10 Ω to 50 Ω requires a step-up of \$1:\sqrt5\$. Think of it this way; if you need to step up the voltage by \$1:\sqrt5\$ then, you are stepping down the current by \$1:\sqrt5\$ and this means that the impedance (V/I) is increasing by: - $$\dfrac{V\times\sqrt5}{I\times\frac{1}{\sqrt5}} = 5\cdot \dfrac{V}{I}$$.

> *How to convert complex conjugate impedance to a usual 50ohm impedance?*

You probably should aim to cancel out the inductive reactive part of the impedance (\$j3.51\$ Ω) by using a series capacitor having a reactance of \$-j3.51\$ Ω. That then leaves you with an impedance (from your [RD16HHF1](https://www.mitsubishielectric.co.jp/semiconductors/content/product/highfrequency/siliconrf/discrete/rd16hhf1.pdf)) of 2.93 Ω.

This would transform to 50 Ω with a transformer of turns ratio \$\sqrt{\dfrac{50}{2.93}}=4.131\$.

Of course, you could use an L-pad transformer like this: -

[image]

Image from [my crappy website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20Lpad%20LP.html).

But, it would be bandwidth limited around 30 MHz with those values. However, a simple simulation would tell you whether it was adequate for your needs or not.

Comment: Under 1:5 transformer I meant Zp:Zs impedance ratio, not a turns ratio. L-network won't fit my needs because I have to cover ham-radio 1.8-30 MHz bands. So I limited to use of the transformer. And your website is not crappy. Its awesome, goes to bookmarks.

Comment: did you have written all the Javascript plots under the hood by hands?

Comment: @zoonman why thank you kind sir. I did all the JS myself

Comment: your website is not crappy! If anything, it reminds me of the times the web was dominated by text and informative graphics rather than bling.

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh yes it is lol (oh no it isn't)

Comment: @Andyaka your work on the website is really good. So don't call it crappy. Going back to the question. I guess 1:4 turns ratio is correct. It seems like we are on the same page here.

Comment: @zoonman It's a tricky one regarding how I call it. On one hand I have to name my picture sources but, on the other hand, I have to take care I don't explicitly advertise any service I might be persuaded to offer people. Between that is a requirement that I also name any services I might provide. These are the site rules and, I took the line that I'll call it "my site" but, add the word "crappy" just so that I feel comfortable as not advertising on this site. It's a tricky one but, compared to sites with "bling" as Marcus calls them, my site might look a little crappy.

Comment: We are on the same page (except how I refer to my site LOL).